# Input unresolved quest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I have this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Qsa8/111/

This input is increasing size when you type a letter as you can see. But here is the issue, when I delete first letter from the end, the input does not decrease, it starts to decrease when I delete the second letter from the end. So the question is how to make input decrease in size on the deleting of the last letter, not on the second, before thanks.

-HTML

```
<div class="resizing-input">
    * <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder"/>
    <span  style="display:none"></span>
</div>
```

-CSS

```
.resizing-input input, .resizing-input span {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

-JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $inputs = $('.resizing-input');

    // Resize based on text if text.length > 0
    // Otherwise resize based on the placeholder
    function resizeForText(text) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!text.trim()) {
            text = $this.attr('placeholder').trim();
        }
        var $span = $this.parent().find('span');
        $span.text(text);
        var $inputSize = $span.width();
        $this.css("width", $inputSize);
    }

    $inputs.find('input').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which && e.charCode) {
            var c = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode | e.charCode);
            var $this = $(this);
            resizeForText.call($this, $this.val() + c);
        }
    });

    // Backspace event only fires for keyup
    $inputs.find('input').keydown(function (e) { 
        if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
            resizeForText.call($(this), $(this).val());
        }
    });

    $inputs.find('input').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        resizeForText.call($this, $this.val())
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keyup` event instead of `keydown` event. because `keydown` event occurs before the input update its value. It will work.

Comment: yea,i knew that,because if i use keyup event i cant hold the delete button,because the input will decrease just when i will 
release the delete button,i dont need that.The input should decrease
at the same time as the text.So how do i resolve that problem now?

Comment: With `keydown` you will remove the last character explicitly and it will work:
`$inputs.find('input').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
          var arr = $(this).val().split("");
            arr.splice((arr.length)-1,1);
            resizeForText.call($(this), arr.join(""));
        }
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Line 26 of the jsfiddle example, change the line:

```
$inputs.find('input').keydown(function (e) {
```

to:

```
$inputs.find('input').keyup(function (e) {
```

Comment: guy before you told me the same,this is not resolving my problem